# Unusual Increment operation in unordered_map/hash_map

Tags: c++, optimization, hashmap, unordered-map

Ive seen people do some obscure short optimizations with unordered_maps. Whats the logic behind `cnt[s[i]]++;` in this code. Why is there an increment and why does the 2nd `a` gets found if a key is usually found with `cnt.at("a")`.

Is there a reference to all/most of these optimizations (that also seem to exist in C). Itd make it easier to understand code written by advanced programmers.

```
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <hash_map>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    int firstUniqChar(string s) {
        unordered_map<char, int> cnt;
        int n = s.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // count letter times
            cnt[s[i]]++;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {//get the first letter occurs once
            if(cnt[s[i]] == 1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution a;
    string s = "aabb";
    a.firstUniqChar(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't know that `std::unordered_map` has an [`operator []`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at).

Answer (score 3):

`cnt[s[i]]++;` is a (rather too-clever) idiom to calculate a histogram of the letters in the string.

In particular:

- `s[i]` returns a reference to the integer associated with the char `s[i]` in the unordered_map.  (It will auto-insert a key/value entry with key=`s[i]` and value=`0` into the unordered_map, if an entry for that key is not already present in the unordered_map)
- The `++` adds one to the value of the key/value pair in the unordered_map.

... so at the end of the for-loop, the unordered_map contains (the set of letters in the string) as keys, and for each key, the corresponding value is the number of times that letter occurs in the string.

Comment: Is there a website or any other reference where I can find these kind of optimizations? Seems like I find them more often the more I progress into the programming world.

Comment: It's not really an optimization, more of an obfuscation.  The only thing it optimizes is the number of keystrokes the person writing the code had to type; OTOH it won't run faster than doing the same thing in a more obvious way, and it is harder to read and understand.

Comment: Isn't this just the normal way to do it, rather than an obfuscation?

Comment: I suppose it's normal if you're used to it; I don't think it's very clear what it's supposed to be doing, at least not to anyone who isn't already familiar with how the non-const `operator[]` works (and that operator's semantics is itself a problem:  https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g?t=423 )